# Mac OS X creating .Spotlight-V100 and .Trashes at MacFUSE mountpoint on root volume

Tags: macos, macfuse

I'm creating a MacFUSE filesystem for adding HFS write support to Mac OS X Snow Leopard, and it mostly works, but the system creates `.Spotlight-V100` and `.Trashes` directories on the mountpoint in `/Volumes` before the volume is actually mounted, so those two directories stay there after the volume is unmounted, which prevents the mountpoint from being deleted. Successive mounts of the same disk create new mountpoints in /Volumes with sequential numbers (/Volumes/Disk, /Volumes/Disk 1, /Volumes/Disk 2, etc), this leads to /Volumes being filled with lots of useless directories unless they are deleted manually.

This happens wether I mark the volume as local or not, with `fuse_opt_add_arg(&args, "-olocal");`

How can I avoid this?

My source code is at http://vc.namedfork.net/nf/fusehfs/trunk/, the filesystem bundle is installed as `/System/Library/Filesystems/fusefs_hfs.fs`, and the mounting is done with a fuse_wait wrapper, like fuse-ext2 and ntfs-3g

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [OSXFuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/) project. It is basically MacFUSE that contains numerous bugfixes. It might happen that the problem is already solved there.